# Entity Framework Core 1.1 crashes when compiled with .net native

Tags: entity-framework, uwp

I have an UWP app who uses Entity Framework Core 1.1 with SQLite. When I run the app in Debug Mode everything works fine. But when I compile as release with .net native to publish it it crashes with a Null Pointer.
On the Output I got this:

```
Exception thrown: 'SQLite.SQLiteException' in SQLite-net.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Linq.Expressions.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: ArgumentNull_Generic
```

[image]

I saw issues on GitHub who had something similar on ARM Devices, but I have it on all of my devices including my Notebook. I tried to set entries to the rd.xaml to fix this issues as recommended in the GitHub issues. But with the entries I made it didn't work either:

```
<Assembly Name="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" DoNotOptimize="true" DoNotInline="true" />
```

I use these packages:

```
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
```

Answer (score 0):

EF Core with UWP is not ready for prime time yet..

From: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap

"Universal Windows Platform (UWP) currently works for local development but there are issues with the .NET Native tool chain that the EF and .NET Native teams are working to address."

Comment: Well, if not on UWP then where it is.. ^^

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's funny. I removed the flag to include the runtime into the package so that is uses the shared and it seems to work now. at least in Release config. I'm trying now to make a build an publish it in my beta flight.